# How to know whether a port is open/close in socket programming?

Tags: python, c, sockets

If a socket program runs on a port(say `6053`) and if the rule is not added in the `firewall` the functions `recv` `read` and `recvfrom` are blocked.

How do we check this in `C` or `python` and report `Port not opened` error on linux machines.

Comment: You will not be able to connect the socket and you will receive an exception after it times out.

Comment: you are interested in figuring out if packets to a port are blocked by some ip-rule  or determine if the port is bound to the program and is ready to recv packets?

Answer (score 3):

Try to connect on that port using socket.connect(), if connection is not successful, then show message that Port not opened.

Comment: Connect fails for other reasons also right? and how about with Udp

Comment: But make sure to use the IP address of your Ethernet/WLAN interface, as it might have stricter rules imposed than the `localhost`...

Comment: You have to check error in order to know why connection failed. In C you will have to check for the `errno` (reasons can be still in use, permission denied, and no-one listening (and others)).

Answer (score 1):

Tools like nmap can help in determining whether the particular port is open or closed.

**TCP :**
nmap uses techniques like TCP SYN scan or TCP Connect scan where the server will reply with ACK-RST packet for SYN request incase of closed port. You can notice  that, it is determined at the time of 3-way handshake (connection establishment) itself.

**UDP :** nmap also facilitates the UDP scan, where ICMP based 'Port Unreachable' packet shall be returned in case the UDP packet arrives on a closed UDP port (This also depends on the stack in the OS). Unlike TCP, the UDP is not a connection-based protocol and ICMP is also connection-less, so you might need to send some significant number of UDP packets for a short interval and evaluate based on the responses or some similar logic.

You can arrive on similar technique/logic and determine whether the particular port is open or closed and flash appropriate message for user.